# The permutation of the signs of sum and integration

Tags: integration

Is it possible to swap sum and integration signs in this integral
$$\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a^nx^{1/2}e^{-nx}dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a^n\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}x^{1/2}e^{-nx}dx$$
provided that $a∈(0;1]$? If it is possible, how to prove the uniform convergence of the series?

Comment: See the limit theorems that you know for integrals.  Does one (or more) of them apply in this case?

Comment: I used the theorem of Weierstrass, 
$$\dfrac{a^nx^{1/2}}{e^{nx}}<\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
but sum
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
diverges